# android database overwrite data on exist data

Tags: android, database

i have a database which have insert,delete,update function database work fine now i add some value to database . i add value in my splash activity like this

```
    foodDbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = foodDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Paratha", "1 piece", 260, "8.99 g", "5.16 g", "2.18 g", "38.94 g");
        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Chapatti", "1 Piece", 68, "0.62 g", "2.34 g", "0.26 g", "13 g");
        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Alu Paratha", "1 Piece", 329, "6.16 g", "9.08 g", "3.9 g", "38.1 g");
        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Vegetable Biryani", "1 Cup", 170, "0 g", "4 g", "8 g", "36 g");
        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Chicken Biryani", "1 Tray", 480, "15 g", "34 g", "0 g", "51 g");

 foodDbHelper.close();
```

it store data in database when app run.but problem is that when every time i run app the data store every time and overwrite the exxisting data . when i update are delete value from database and again run the app value again store in database i want when i delete or update any value .and start again app it does not store the deleted value to database.

Comment: if these are some initial values, you can store a flag in Preferences that the values were added... if not, then they have to be `onClick()` based on some actions by user, not on startup, sa7? i mean why you have these inserts on startup?

Comment: because these value is in the project i want when user 1st time install app these value should be store in database just one time not every time when user start app

Comment: yes as i told you, you can store a flag in `Preferences` that initial data was inserted, then next startup you don;t insert them again, or simply you can check that the table you are inserting in is NOT empty. ella eza bt3ali insert be aktar mn table, so Preferences a7san

Comment: I DONT know about preferences will you please tell me with some code

Comment: tayeb tayeb :) find answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code basically check if a key `INIT_DATA_INSERTED` is stored in Preferences, with value == `true`
this key flag determine if init data is inserted or not,
and if not, the data is inserted, and the key value is set to `true`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

if (!prefs.getBoolean("INIT_DATA_INSERTED", false)) {
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("INIT_DATA_INSERTED", true);
    editor.commit();

    foodDbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = foodDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Paratha", "1 piece", 260, "8.99 g", "5.16 g", "2.18 g", "38.94 g");
        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Chapatti", "1 Piece", 68, "0.62 g", "2.34 g", "0.26 g", "13 g");
        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Alu Paratha", "1 Piece", 329, "6.16 g", "9.08 g", "3.9 g", "38.1 g");
        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Vegetable Biryani", "1 Cup", 170, "0 g", "4 g", "8 g", "36 g");
        foodDbHelper.addInformations
                ("Chicken Biryani", "1 Tray", 480, "15 g", "34 g", "0 g", "51 g");

    foodDbHelper.close();
}
```

Comment: sorry, you can use `context` instead of `getContext()`